# need to unify child form button clicks into one routine

Tags: c#, winforms

I have discovered that I am beginning to use the same code for a few different click events.  I have a MDI form and there are "master children" as I call them that will open other children associated with the master.  This is the master/detail thing going on.  An example is the Company master child will have buttons to open the Contact, Industry, etc associated with the Company.  Below is a sample of the code that opens the Contact child form.  This code is also being used for the others as well.

What I am looking to do is to be able to use just one and fill in the button, form, message, and a connection label between Company and Contact.  The code at the botton is what I have so far and I marked the lines that need to be changed with what I'm looking for.  The lines with the single arrow "seem" to work but the multi arrow line can't get it right.  Providing both for comparison reasons.

Could someone look this/these over and see what I'm doing wrong (or missing) in the consolidated code?

Thanks...John

//CODE TO OPEN THE CONTACT CHILD FORM

```
        private void btnCompanyContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isOpen = false;

        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (f is frmContact)
            {
                isOpen = true;
                MessageBox.Show("The Contact list is already open.", "INFORMATION", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                f.BringToFront();
                f.Controls["lblRecordID"].Text = lblCompanyID.Text;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isOpen)
        {
            frmContact contact = new frmContact();
            contact.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
            contact.ReceiveValue(lblCompanyID.Text);
            contact.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            contact.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            contact.Show();
        }

        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

//CONSOLIDATE ALL THE BUTTON OPENING INTO THIS ROUTINE

```
        private void OpenCompanyInformationForm(Button btn, Form name, string message, string lbl)
    {
        bool isOpen = false;

        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
  ->        if (f == name)
            {
                isOpen = true;
  ->            MessageBox.Show("The " + message + " list is already open.", "INFORMATION", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                f.BringToFront();
  ->            f.Controls[lbl].Text = lblCompanyID.Text;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isOpen)
        {
   ->->->   frmContact contact = new frmContact();
            contact.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
            contact.ReceiveValue(lblCompanyID.Text);
            contact.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            contact.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            contact.Show();
        }

        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you just trying to reuse the same piece code in all forms??

Comment: For now it is just in the one master child form that will have 6 other child forms to open to show data.  But since you mention it, there could be some similarity across others.

Comment: I am still not sure of the question. But a guess on the fly is, can inheritance solve your problem?? I mean create a class with common functionality and derive rest of the classes from it. Your common class can even contain buttons and their events.

Comment: What about what is posted?  Is it possible to modify that so as to be able to manage the opening of the forms from the different buttons?  The reason is, a gut feeling actually, is that after the start of the new year there could be a "change" coming as to what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

To perfom the custom function ReceiveValue you need to create a derived class from Form
and create all you forms from this derived class

```
public class ContactBase : Form
{

    public void ReceiveValue(string p_Value)
    {
        Button button = (Button)this.Controls["lblRecordID"];
        if (button == null) return;
        button.Text = p_Value;
    }

}


private void OpenCompanyInformationForm(Form name)
    {
        bool isOpen = false;

        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            // Just to compare, you can use the Name property
  ->        if (f.Name == name.Name)
            {
                isOpen = true;
                // If the message is just a name of form, you can use Name or Text property
                // in this case you can supress message param
  ->            MessageBox.Show("The " + f.Text + " list is already open.", "INFORMATION", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                f.BringToFront();
                // If the ReceiveValue is just to pass the text of lblCompanyID for lblRecordID button, you can use the function here
  ->            ((ContactBase)name).ReceiveValue(lblCompanyID.Text);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isOpen)
        {
   ->->->   ContactBase contact = (ContactBase)Activator.CreateInstance(name.GetType());
            contact.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
            contact.ReceiveValue(lblCompanyID.Text);
            contact.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            contact.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            contact.Show();
        }

        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```